# Is it possible to edit text file which is inside an image that runs on docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a python script which I use  docker to run by creating a docker image inside a docker container. This is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN pip install tweepy
RUN pip install pymongo
RUN pip install asyncio
EXPOSE 32771
ADD hash_cat.txt /
ADD tweepy_twitter_stream_v0.6.py /
CMD [ "python", "./tweepy_twitter_stream_v0.6.py" ]
```

The script reads from **hash_cat.txt** text file and execute some stuff based on its content. 
I want to access **hash_cat.txt** regularly and change its content.

**The problem is:** 
when I run the image to access its bash and edit the **hash_cat.txt** and save it , it creates a new container for the image with the **hash_cat.txt** file without saving the changes I had made to **hash_cat.txt**. 
This is how I run the image shell to edit **hash_cat.txt** content:

```
docker run -it python_script bin/bash
```

Where python_script is the image name.
Then I run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

to use vim to edit **hash_cat.txt** content.
After I edited the file and typed :wq to save and exit.
I run the image again using

```
docker run python_script
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to run the image and access it regularly and change **hash_cat.txt** content without creating a new container every time.

Hope you understood my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you use `docker run` there will be a new container, use `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash` to visit already existed container please.

Or you had to use volume, and put this file in volume.

Comment: Thanks a lot @atline